# Issue upgrading from 20.10(groovy, no longer suported) to 22.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, do-release-upgrade, 22.04

so against common sense I've been putting off upgrading my system for a while, some things started to not work as intended recently(I assume because repos are no longer updated, or officially supported among other things), so I decided it was time to upgrade.

Since groovy is EOL, a direct upgrade to jammy is not available through the usual tool, so I followed the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades, and ended up downloading the upgrader tool for hirsute, which seems to be the only one that works for groovy, and then I'd upgrade from it to further versions. But for some reason the tool always freezes
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80aRL.png) (">setting new software channels"),
and then sends me [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWYQ5.png) (telling me to check my network)
Which doesn't help much, since I clearly do have network.

I tried then to install hirsute from a bootable USB, but an option to upgrade isn't available, I would like not to completely lose my setup to start fresh, if possible.
[This is my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuuIp.png), I have 20.10 installed on a 250GB nvme, and a 500GB sda also with a 20.10 system installed, but I basically just use it as a slave

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10 x86_64
- Kernel: 5.8.0-63-generic
- Shell: bash 5.0.17
- DE: GNOME 3.38.3
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600XT (12) @ 3.800
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
- Memory: 2016MiB / 15993MiB

Thanks in advance for anyone taking the time to read this, if you could help it'd be greatly appreciated.
Please let me know what other info I could provide

Comment: As far as I know you can just hop from one version to another.No chance to update 20.10 to 22.04. I'd advice you to save your data and make a fresh install

Comment: Seems from your description like the upgrader cannot reach the Hirsute (20.10) repositories. That's expected behavior: That release is also EOL, those repos were withdrawn, and you missed the upgrade window by about three months. I recommend backing up your data and doing a fresh install of 22.04. That will be much faster and easier than your path of multiple sequential release-upgrades.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) - The short answer is "No, you cannot upgrade".  You waited too long to expect an upgrade to go successfully. Not only is 20.10 EOL, but 21.04 is also EOL. In order for the upgrade path to be supported, you must upgrade *before* the EOL date. If you choose standard releases that means you have to upgrade every 6-9 months. If you can't do that, use LTS releases

Comment: See also: [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430)  Again, the short answer is "No". Release upgrades are only supported to upgrade from one release to the next. In the case of 20.10 the only supported upgrade for that release was to upgrade to 21.04.  From 21.04 you would have had to upgrade to 21.10 to be able to upgrade to 22.04.  At this point you are so far behind that it's probably better to cleanly reinstall 22.04. Do not allow your release to go EOL- in addition to not being able to upgrade, you also don't get security patches or critical bigfixes

Comment: If you install 22.04 LTS and stick with LTS releases, it won't be until 24.04.1 that the next upgrade will be available and you can even wait until **2027** to upgrade to 24.04.  Of course you should still keep your packages up-to-date through regular system maintenance updates.

Comment: Yes 20.10 upgraded to 21.04; however as [21.04 is EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) now, the upgrade cycle is gone, and problems with 21.04 are to be expected.  The *fully supported* upgrade path (*given you missed the 9 months of intended upgrade path*) is via re-install; though desktop systems can be *upgraded via re-install* (re-use existing partitions; & don't format having internet connection for re-downloading of *manually installed* packages from Ubuntu repositories) but it's only QA-tested with Ubuntu repos

Comment: You weren't specific with 20.10 details (desktop? server?) but desktop systems are easier to *upgrade via reinstall* (system directories get wiped, and as many server apps store *conf* files in system directories these will be wiped).  Read release notes & upgrade notes before hand to avoid this issue, 20.10 was 2020-October release (*year.month* format add 2000 to year) and upgrade path was gone when next release (21.04 or 2021-April; 6 months later) was EOL; ie. easy to plan (2020.10 + 9 months supported life, upgrade path gone in 15 months). The *year.month* format makes planning easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135901/discussion-between-nmath-and-guiverc).

Comment: Alright, it seems like I'll have no other choice but to do a fresh install of 22.04, so I will be doing that, as like you've all said, it will probably be less of headache anyways. Thanks everyone for your answers, I'll be sure to pay more attention in the future.

Comment: You perform the *upgrade via re-install* by selecting your existing partitions **without** format (the lack of *format* triggers this type of install with Desktop systems).  The causes your *manually installed* packages to be noted, system directories are erased (*the problem with server apps/systems*), new system installed from media, then if internet is available, the *manually installed* packages noted earlier are downloaded and installed IF packages are available in the new release from Ubuntu repositories..  There is **no** upgrade via re-install option; it's triggered by what you do